# Custom ML kit tflite model on firebase integrate to Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I have a custom Tensorflow lite(tflite) model on firebase custom ML kit. I want to integrate it with Flutter Android. I am beginner and cannot really find a way to do it. I have seen firebase documentation but it never helps where to add that code snippet.
My model is of image classification which predicts labels of images as output given specific image as input. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried the tflite package?

Comment: @NgLokChun Yes, initially I have integrated the tflite model in local directory with Flutter Android using its package. Now I want to publish it on firebase custom ML kit and get the same functionality as like model in local directory